# Change the background color of some lines in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: pyqt

This does not work:

```
    def lineError(self):
        block= self.firstVisibleBlock()
        while block.isValid():
            if block.blockNumber() in self.lineError:
                block.blockFormat().setBackground(QBrush(self.errorColor))
                block.charFormat().setBackground(QBrush(self.errorColor))
            block= block.next()
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I Fixed a typo in your question. A more detailed description of the error should be included im the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have not mentioned error because there is none. It does not change the background color that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way:

```
        fmt= QTextBlockFormat()
        fmt.setBackground(self.errorColor)
        while block.isValid():
            if block.blockNumber() in self.lineError:
                QTextCursor(block).setBlockFormat(fmt)
            block= block.next()
```